# postgresql remove stale lock

Tags: postgresql, locking

After a system crash my Postgresql database does have a lock on a row.

The `pg_locks` table contains a lot of rows without a pid. i.e.

`select locktype,database,relation,virtualtransaction, pid,mode,granted from pg_locks p1;`

```
locktype    | database | relation | virtualtransaction |  pid  |       mode       | granted 
---------------+----------+----------+--------------------+-------+------------------+---------
 relation      |    16408 |    31459 | -1/40059           |       | AccessShareLock  | t
 relation      |    16408 |    31459 | -1/40059           |       | RowExclusiveLock | t
 relation      |    16408 |    31022 | -1/40060           |       | AccessShareLock  | t
 transactionid |          |          | -1/40060           |       | ExclusiveLock    | t
 relation      |    16408 |    31485 | -1/40060           |       | AccessShareLock  | t
```

How do I get the transaction 40060 killed and the locks removed?

Comment: OK, I found the solution of the problem:

Answer (score 6):

Ok, solution found by myself:

1. Find the gid to the transaction (i.e. 40060 in the case above) by `select * from pg_prepared_xacts where transaction = 40060;`
2. Find an awful long gid.
3. `ROLLBACK PREPARED gid;`

This will clear the locks.